# PHP : it is not working fine for Feb 2022. it only gives 4 weeks limited upto 27 feb while 28feb is remaining as fifth week day. please resolve it

Tags: php

```
$month = '2';
$year = '2022';
$lastDayOfWeek = '7'; //1 (for monday) to 7 (for sunday)

function getWeeksInMonth($year, $month, $lastDayOfWeek)
{
    $aWeeksOfMonth = [];
    $date = new DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
    $iDaysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $aOneWeek = [$date->format('Y-m-d')];
    $weekNumber = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $iDaysInMonth; $i++)
    {
        if ($lastDayOfWeek == $date->format('N') || $i == $iDaysInMonth)
        {
            $aOneWeek[]      = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $aWeeksOfMonth[$weekNumber++] = $aOneWeek;
            $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
            $aOneWeek = [$date->format('Y-m-d')];
            $i++;

        }
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    return $aWeeksOfMonth;
}

$weeks = getWeeksInMonth($year, $month, $lastDayOfWeek);

foreach($weeks as $weekNumber => $week){
    echo "Week {$weekNumber}: {$week[0]} - {$week[1]}";
    echo '<br>';
```

}

OUTPUT
Week 1: 2022-02-01 - 2022-02-06
Week 2: 2022-02-07 - 2022-02-13
Week 3: 2022-02-14 - 2022-02-20
Week 4: 2022-02-21 - 2022-02-27

Comment: So you want to count not natural weeks (i.e. as they appear on the calendar) but in chunks of seven days, despite what week they are one? Wouldn't be enough using division / modulo on the number of days in the month?

Comment: not it is all about the total weeks and in a particular month and date range in each week like Week 1: 2022-02-01 - 2022-02-06
Week 2: 2022-02-07 - 2022-02-13
Week 3: 2022-02-14 - 2022-02-20
Week 4: 2022-02-21 - 2022-02-27

Comment: That's what I get by running this code. What's your _desired_ output? And why do you increment `$i` inside the `if` block?

Comment: here days are being incremented. You can run the whole code except the output you will understand everything about the functionality

Comment: I did... and since 27 is `$lastDayOfWeek`, `$i` gets incremented and day 28 skipped.